# Не могу добавить элемент в вектор пользовательского типа

Tags: c++, классы, вектор

При попытке в функции NewCitizen добавить строку в вектор A выскакивает ошибка ниже

Как можно запихнуть строку туда, не меняя тип данных вектора?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Citizen
{
private:
    string first_name;
    string second_name;
    string birthday[3];
    string status;

public:
    void EnterData()
    {
        cout << "Введите фамилию, имя и дату рождения гражданина\n";
        getline(cin, first_name, '\t');
        getline(cin, second_name, '\t');
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            getline(cin,birthday[i], '/' );
        }
    }
};

void NewCitizen(vector <Citizen> &A)
{
    string name ; 
    printf("Введите имя гражданина"); getline(cin, name, '\t');
    A.push_back(name);
}
int main()
{
    bool reset = false; char choose;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    vector <Citizen> Citizens;
    while (reset != true)
    {
        printf("Меню\n1.Создать нового гражданина\n2.Удалить гражданина\n3.Вывести список гражданинов\n4.Вывести информацию о гражданинах\nQ.Завершить программу");
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose)
        {
        case '1': 
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case 'Q':
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в векторе хранятся не строки, а объекты Citizen.

Comment: `vector <Citizen> &A` - вектор чего? Правильно, `Citizen`. А вы в него что запихиваете? `string`. Что ж удивительного, что компилятор сопротивляется?...

Comment: может вам нужен конструктор, который бы принимал имя?